# Robot Framework Absolute Value (number)

Tags: robotframework

Looking for a way how to represent the modulus/absolute value in Robot Framework.
Is it abs() ?  or ${variable}.abs()?
How I can make my ${variable} with negative value -15 to be +15

Like this:
|-15| = 15

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use Evaluate keyword to run abs function to your number:

```
*** Variables ***
${neg num}     -15

*** Test Cases ***
Absolute
    Log    ${neg num}
    ${num}=    Evaluate    abs(${neg num})
```

Comment: ${LoggedInGrowthAmount} = −85       ${LoggedInGrowthAmount} = BuiltIn . Evaluate abs(${LoggedInGrowthAmount})           FAIL Evaluating expression 'abs(−85)' failed: SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier (<string>, line 1)

Answer (score 5):

In case you need an alternative to Pekka's perfectly optimal answer here it is:

```
*** Variables ***
${var}     -15

*** Test Cases ***
Absolute
  Log    ${var}
  ${abs var}=    Set Variable    ${var.__abs__()}
```